# eclipse update - unsupported content type for htm/css

Tags: eclipse, jboss-tools

I had eclipse 2023-03 working fine. I updated to 2023-06 and not get the dreaded Unsupported content type in editor when I open any .htm/.css or anything that uses the jboss tools html editor.

It tells me to edit the content types but it already says that .htm is associated with jboss tools.

When I open the file it does open, the icon on the tab shows the jboss tools htm icon, but we have no formatting. Meanwhile, we can exit the xhtml files just fine, highlighting and everything.

I don't have it installed anymore, but a historical log shows this:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 2 2 2023-07-12 15:57:40.659
!MESSAGE StructuredTextEditor being used without StructuredDocument

!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 2 2 2023-07-12 15:57:40.660
!MESSAGE          Input Name: about.html

!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 2 2 2023-07-12 15:57:40.661
!MESSAGE         Unexpected IDocumentProvider implementation: org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider

!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 2 2 2023-07-12 15:57:40.662
!MESSAGE         Unexpected IDocument implementation: org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.SynchronizableDocument
```

After more research, can replicate with 2023-06:

- install eclispe for java and web default.
- go to marketplace and install jboss-tools. Default version from marketplace
- create new web project, any blank test name
- create html file, give it any name like test.htm
- Open the file
- i get the error pop-up saying Unsupported content type.
- file is opened but no formatting or anything

Same steps works fine with 2023-03. So I just went back to 2023-03 and will update for a while. :-)

Comment: Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error, hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_. Which version of JBoss Tools do you have? Is it up to date?

Comment: I removed the offending version but was able to find a .bak_0.log and updated above. I was able to duplicate from clean build. This is ONLY with 2023-06 and the latest jboss-tools. Does not happen on 2023-03.

Comment: To replicate:
- install eclispe for java and web default.
- go to marketplace and install jboss-tools. Default version from marketplace
- create new web project, any blank test name
- create html file, give it any name like test.htm
- Open the file
- i get the error pop-up saying Unsupported content type.
- file is opened but no formatting or anything

Same steps works fine with 2023-03.

Comment: Hi, i've created https://issues.redhat.com/browse/JBIDE-29049, because it is indeed a regression.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the issue. In Eclipse 2023-09, it is still broken. However, in Eclipse 2023-03, it works fine. I switched back to Eclipse 2023-03.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).